# PHP Port Problem

Tags: php

I'm using a PHP script to detect of a referral URL is a proxy. This is a very simplified version but it works great.

The problem is that I'm trying to use the same script on my other web server but for reasons am not copying over the script. What I'm doing instead is using a **get_file_contents**.

My problem is that when I use **get_file_contents** it detects it as a proxy. Is there anyway around this, possibly by changing the port?

```
<?php $stop = file_get_contents("http://mysite.com/file.php"); echo $stop; ?>
```

Any help would be great, Thanks!

Comment: is this done cross-domain or within your own domain?

Comment: Pretty sure you can't access files across another domain with the file() functions.  Use PECL SSH2.

Comment: I can access the file fine, its just that it picks it up as a bad referral. Is there simply a way changing the port?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`file_get_contents` with a remote URL is very different from a local URL -- you are actually running the script on `mysite.com` and simply getting the output of that script on your local server. This actually sends another HTTP request to `mysite.com`, so the referrer for that request is different from the referrer for your original request.

Comment: @Alexwhin - as tandu said in question comments - use PECL SSH2

Comment: @Alexwhin: Simple solution would be to copy the script to your local server. If you can't do that, you could use [cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) to manually send a HTTP request and specify your own referrer value (see [`curl_setopt`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php))

Comment: Still found it as a bad referral.

Comment: @Alexwhin: Does that script really use the HTTP referrer or something else, such as IP address? In case it uses an IP address, there is no way you can get it to work from your own server because the IP will always be different from that of the original request.

Comment: It uses: if( @fsockopen( $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], 80, $errstr, $errno, 1 ) ){

Comment: @Alexwhin: Yes, then it is using the IP address of the remote server and rejects it if it is running a server on port 80. You could probably change the script to allow your IP address.

Comment: Possibly using something like this: 

if (($HTTP_REFERRER == 'www.sitewithincludeon.com')){ }else{ if( @fsockopen( $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], 80, $errstr, $errno, 1 ) ){

Comment: You can use streams support in file_get_contents to set arbitrary HTTP headers, including the referer. See Example #4 on the man page for the function: http://php.net/file_get_contents

Comment: I don't really understand, could you give me an example please.